# using @UseGuards(AuthGuard) in another module/route - Nest JS

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I am implementing authentication and authorization system.

Following the Nest JS examples about authentication, the examples do not demonstrate, at least more clearly, how to place the authentication requirement on only some routes.

https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

The example shows only in the Auth module, or globally in all routes, having to use @Public()

My goal is to create the authentication system, but be able to define who uses it just by passing @UseGuards(AuthGuard);

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';

export const jwtConstant = "OANSOCOON!@NO!@#ON!@#ONN"

@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: jwtConstant,
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: '30 days'
      }
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**users.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [DatabaseModule],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'users_model',
            useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('users', UserSchema),
            inject: ['DATABASE_CONNECTION'],
        },
        UsersService,
        CaslAbilityFactory
    ],
    exports: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**users.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {

    constructor(
        private usersService: UsersService,
        private caslAbility: CaslAbilityFactory
    ) { }

    @Get()
    findAll() {
        return this.usersService.findAll()
    }

    // @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    @Get(":id")
    findOnById(@Param('id') id: any, @Request() req) {
        console.log(req.user)
        return req.user
        return this.usersService.findById(id)
    }
}
```

The **error** when using @UserGuards(AuthGuard) is:

```
throw new InvalidDecoratorItemException(decorator, item, context.name);              ^
Error: Invalid guard passed to @UseGuards() decorator (AuthController).
```

I tried to import the AuthModule inside the UserModule, it generated circular dependency, I fixed it, but the error in the decorator still remained.

**EDIT**

**auth.controller.ts**

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

    @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Post('login')
    signIn(@Body() signInDto: LoginArgDto) {
        return this.authService.signIn(signInDto.username, signInDto.password);
    }

    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    @Get('profile')
    profile(@Request() req) {
        return req.user
    }
}
```

**repository**

https://github.com/ricardosc12/nest-js-architecture/settings

> **It's in the hotfix/jwt branch**

**For those facing this problem**
I decided to implement using passport, the examples I followed were from the [Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#customize-passport) and this [github](https://github.com/elvisduru/token-auth-app/tree/master/src/auth)

Comment: Are you certain that `AuthGuard` inside your `AuthController` is imported as the actual class and not coming in as `undefined`?

Comment: in auth.controller the decorator @UseGuards(AuthGuard) works, it is in another module that does not, for example in users.controller

Comment: The error is indicating it's coming from `AuthController`, right?

Comment: yep, at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ricar\Documents\Back-End-Estudos\nest-project\src\routes\auth\auth.controller.ts:21:5)

Comment: I will update to show how AuthController is, but this error only appears when I use @UseGuards(AuthGuard) in user.controller, if I remove it from there, auth.controller does not show an error.

Comment: The error's stack trace points to `auth.controller.ts`. I would bet there's a circular file import somewhere

Comment: I decided to implement using passport, and following the examples in the documentation it worked, but I would still expect the basic example to work, I linked the repository if you want to take a look, it's in the hotfix/jwt branch

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, as I mentioned in the comments, is that there is a circular file import. Your `~/nest-project/src/routes/users/users.controller.ts` imports `~/nest-project/src/routes/auth/auth.guard.ts` which imports `~/nest-project/src/routes/auth/auth.module.ts` which imports `~/nest-project/src/routes/users/user.module.ts` which imports `~/nest-project/src/routes/users/users.controller.ts` and we've come full circle. This causes the `AuthGuard` to be imported as `undefined` because the import chain cannot be properly resolved by node until after the metadata is already set, and so Nest ends up reading `@UseGuards(undefined)`.

To fix this, move the `jwtConstant` to an `auth.constants.ts` file and import from that instead of the `auth.module.ts` file. A general rule of thumb is that it's never good to import from the `*.module.ts` file unless you are importing from another module.